# Attach file like doc,PDF,etc... to application in iphone

Tags: ios, iphone

I want to attache file in my iphone application than what i do? i attach here my screenshot for better understanding.[image]

in my screenshot the arrows are point is button and on this button click i want to attach file.
i'm new in ios development so please help me if this is possible then give me link or answer. I did search on this topic but every link gives email attachment so i was not get proper answer if anybody can done this in past than please help me.
Thank you in Advance!!

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean by "attach".  What do you actually want to do with the file?  And where will the file come from?

Comment: Like I want to select Doc or PDF from iphone and post to server.. so How can I attach.. Post I know..

Comment: And what is the location of your file? Source of file

Comment: @SatishAzad  from iPhone as we are selecting file from Android SDCard. so in iPhone how we list All file and select PDF , txt , Doc etc.

Comment: In iPhone there is no memory as like SDCard in Android. and you cannot access files of other applications.

Comment: @SatishAzad Like we accessing file from our application resource folder so How we access from iphone.?

Comment: @SatishAzad you got me I want to tap on button to list all file and select file and then send to my server...

Comment: For this there is no in-built library. You need to write code and create a View to list all files on that view either using TableView or CollectionView or any other.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56117/discussion-between-jay-raparka-and-satish-azad).

Comment: @JAYRAPARKA , have you got any conclusion , so please tell me how can i do this?

Comment: @RaviJSS sry my friend this will not done in iphone Bcoz iphone could not giviing authority Memory so.

Comment: Ya you can do this storying files in document dir and like creating custom gallery in your app .

Answer (score 0):

You can browse all file in your application dir by:

```
NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];

NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray *fileList = [manager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:nil];
for (NSString *s in fileList){
    NSLog(@"%@", s);
}
```

and from here list all file on your ViewController.

Comment: He seems to want the application resources.  If that's true, it would be `[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];`.

Comment: i just want to attach file like we can pic image using image picker.

Comment: @JAYRAPARKA: nothing can be done automatically likewise ImagePicker. You have to implement everything.

Comment: ya bro i understand i only understand you that my main requirement is like that.